# Замена объекта из массива

Tags: android

Есть массив из фото (из 25 штук):

```
private int[] image_res = {R.drawable.res_null, R.drawable.res_null, R.drawable.res_null}
```

Пытаюсь заменить фото на другое фото. Использую `image_res.set(2, R.drawable.rees_ok);` но пишет

> cannot resolve method set (int, int).

Какую ошибку я допускаю?

Comment: Думаю, ошибка в том, что вы не воспринимаете всерьез сообщения об ошибках. Читайте их, обычно там всё очень понятно. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так у Вас же **массив**, а не коллекция.

Установка значения в массив происходит так:

```
image_res[2] = R.drawable.rees_ok;
```

Answer (score 3):

вы путаете тип объекта с которым работаете.

```
    image_res[2] = R.drawable.rees_ok;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так у массива нет такого метода

```
ArrayList<Integer> image_res = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new int[]{R.drawable.res_null, R.drawable.res_null, R.drawable.res_null}))
image_res.set(2, R.drawable.rees_ok);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете обычный массив для хранения своих фотографий, он не реализует такой метод. Самый топорный способ решить вашу задачу:

```
for (int i = 0; i < image_res.length; i++)
{
    if (image_res[i] == A)
    {
        A = B;
    }
}
```

Это плохой вариант.

UPD: разумеется, это если индекс заменяемого элемента неизвестен.

Используемый вами метод реализуется в классе ArrayList. Подумайте, не использовать ли в вашем случае такую структуру?